# Swift 2.1 - NSDateFormatter Weird bug

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, nsdateformatter

Good day! I'm trying to make a Date Picker using [this](https://github.com/squimer/DatePickerDialog-iOS-Swift) date picker dialog. Now I'm having problem on setting the `defaultDate` Option, It requires NSDate so i made this.

```
let date = NSDate()
let formatter1 = NSDateFormatter()
formatter1.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
formatter1.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
formatter1.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 28800)
let gmt8TimeZone = formatter1.stringFromDate(date)
let dateToday = formatter1.dateFromString(gmt8TimeZone)
print("\(gmt8TimeZone) - \(dateToday!)")

DatePickerDialog().show("Choose Date", doneButtonTitle: "Done", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", defaultDate: dateToday!, datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode.Date) { (date) -> Void in
    self.dateSelected = date
    self.showTimePicker()
}
```

The problem is, It's not starting on the `defaultDate` that i set which is `dateToday`. So what I did is I print the date string which is `gmt8TimeZone` and `dateToday` and it gives me this `Nov 25 - 2000-11-24 16:00:00 +0000` why is it giving me different dates? it should be the same right? What I have done wrong?

Comment: string extracted from date and printing nsdate object itself gives different values I guess as NSDate object takes a default +0000 GMT.

Comment: @LEVIS OGCPAS Why are you changing the time zone?

Comment: All the date that the user submits must be from GMT+8, Users have different timezones on their  phones, so i want to make it uniformed.

Comment: @LEVISOGCPAS You don't need to do that. NSDate do not store time zones just display it using local time which it is the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply provide NSDate() to the defaultDate parameter.

NSDate is basically a timestamp, a fixed and absolute point in time, and is not linked to any timeZone: NSDate() is absolutely, totally, *now*.

When you fiddle with NSDateFormatter to "fix" it, you move out of the absolute timestamp world to enter the strings world "yyyy-mm-dd..." which indeed require time zones to be interpreted as points in time. And since you mess with it, your date drifts.